# Procedure for computing double integrals with absolute values?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Is there a general procedure to follow when evaluating double integrals of absolute values of a two-variable function? If so, could someone explain this to me? And if not, what's the thought process I should use when attempting one of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is common when computing integrals, there is no general procedure to apply.

Anyway, when in presence of absolute values, the most simple thing to do is to try to split the integration domain in sub-domains where the sign of the arguments of the absolute values is known, so that in each sub-domain it is possible to properly "remove" the absolute values.